# import full block error

Tags: node

~/tezos/tezos-node snapshot import mainnet.full --data-dir /mnt/data/tezos

data from :https://tezosshots.com/ mainnet.full

When I use alove command ,I got a error:

snapshot: Setting current head to block BLFEN3YgnQu4EWomdx9mAa3bqAzVxK7iowQy27Wy9j4wZYMNY4M
Nov  3 12:22:42 - node.main: Cleaning directory /mnt/data/tezos because of failure
tezos-node: Error:
              Invalid block BLFEN3YgnQu4
                Failed to validate the economic-protocol content of the block: Error:
                                                                                Invalid signature for block BLFEN3YgnQu4. Expected: tz1c8TSSGtVtg.

Comment: Is your node compiled from the mainnet branch ? Not the master one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is wrong. You need to download the file from https://tezosshots.com/; put it into your Tezos folder and import.

Try: `~/tezos/tezos-node snapshot import mainnet.full --data-dir /mnt/data/tezos`

Comment: I am using this command, sorry I didn't wrap

Comment: Thank for you help on the slack. my mistake. it's a tezos-node version problem.